# Radio button jQuery change doesn't work

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button

sorry if this is a repost, I've looked around and cannot find a solution that works.

I have to radio buttons, and I want to execute a function when they are changed. From other posts I thought this should work

```
$(function() {
    $("#isMale").change( function() {
        alert("test");
        location.href = 'http://google.com'
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BfMYF/1/

But it doesn't, can anyone help ?

Comment: `isMale` is not the `id`. it's the `name`.

Comment: ^^ should be `$('#male')`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BfMYF/3/ there fixed it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector is wrong, but you need to close .change function brackets properly too:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name=isMale]").change( function() {
        alert("test");
        location.href = 'http://google.com';
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm quite new to jQuery and the syntax in not yet completely in my fingers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#male,#female").change(function () {
        alert("test");
        location.href = 'http://google.com';
    });
});
```

You also had a missing semi and paran!